# Cannot install apk file /run app after add admob library in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, admob

Please help me resolve the problem, I've completed my flutter project without admob  library. It run well. Then, I add admob library as below:

[image]

Of course, I've tried some admob versions but they are the same problem. I stuck on installing apk file.

[image]

installing apk file is not able to finish. If I remove admob library, it works well again. How can I fix the problem ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: try flutter clean and then flutter build apk

Comment: @PraneethDhanushkaFernando: Yes, i do that many times, but it is not resolved :(

Answer (score 0):

Look for your MainActivity package and your AndroidManifest package info. They need to be the same. In MainActivity it is the very first line in the file usually. In android manifest it's the second line of the file usually.

In my case, I changed the name of the app and MainActivity package changed names too.  After changing it to reflect the exactly same of AndroidManifest, it worked fine.